# Day/night cycle via eclipses for mini-star system

Tags: astronomy

I've been thinking of a setting on a tidally locked outer moon world of a mini star system orbiting in a larger star system. It distance makes the dayside habitable with constant sunlight. At least four other moons orbit this star as well. I was wondering if there can be a similar day/night cycle to earth by one or more of the other moons eclipsing the star during their orbit? 
I was thinking of a larger moon on an elliptical orbit that syncs up with this world half way during it's orbit.

Comment: Possibly related to [Planet Tidally-Locked to its star having eclipse day/night cycles?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/80917/32451)

Comment: It isn't entirely clear what you're asking or what the set-up you're describing is, check out other questions on this site to see if any of them match what you're asking for and, if not, then drawing the positions of the different bodies you're interested in could help.

Comment: Contextually, this is a duplicate of the question noted by @Alexander.  The easy answer is "no."  Moons cast very small shadows.  A moon large enough or close enough to cast a shadow covering even 50% of the habited moon would have so much gravitic influence on the habited moon that it would not be tidally locked.  Many moons do not solve this problem as they would all still sum up to the orbit-shifting gravitic influence.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking here. Note moons orbit planets, planets orbit stars.